# Android TextView setText doesn't work, but setTextColor does work?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I've got a ListView in an Android Fragment, with a SimpleCursorAdapter filling in the rows. The fragment itself is set as the ListView's OnItemClickListener.

When an item is clicked, the following code is run:

```
 @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
    textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    textView.setText("Hello");
}
```

The text color DOES change to red, but the actual text DOES NOT change to "Hello".

However, if I get a reference to the same textview from code elsewhere in my app (not in the fragment or in a callback), both calls work fine and the text changes to "Hello".

Does anyone have any idea why setTextColor would work, but setText wouldn't work, from within the callback, but outside the callback both work?

Thanks.

EDIT: This only happens on my phone, which is API level 15. On an API 17 emulator, the problem does not occur, both the color and text change...

Comment: Just checking, what happens if you do `TextView textView = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.title);` ?

Comment: The same, the color changes but not the text.

Comment: @joe_deniable you are getting your answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code makes the adapter to redraw the item.
So you get a call for `getView()` for the very same item.

I guess you are calling `setText()` in `getView()`, but not `setTextColor()`.
And you are recycling the view.

Comment: I'm user a SQLite Cursor adapter, with a custom viewbinder, but I haven't overridden setViewValue for the title column. However, if I do override it, and call setTextColor there, this stops the text turning red when the item is clicked. So it must also be the cause of the text not changing. Thanks. -- One odd thing though is that the issue only occurs on my phone, which is API level 15. On an emulator with API level 17, the issue completely disappears, I can change the color and the text from the onItemClick method...

Comment: Maybe on API 17, the adapter is not forced to redraw the view and just keeps it the way it is. In any case. try to remember the state somewhere and change it in `getView()` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are setting textview text 2 times again changing to default text check thoroughly

Answer (score 0):

try catching the exception

```
 @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
    textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
  try {
    textView.setText("Hello");
  } catch (MyException e){
    throw new IOException(e.toString());
  }
}
```

and see what happens

Comment: I tried catching the general Exception, but there wasn't one.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.

```
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View row, int position, long id) {
        int diplayPosition= position-parent.getFirstVisiblePosition();
            for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
                TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.title);
                textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                textView.setText("Hello");

            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`ListView` tries to be efficient by recycling views generated by its adapter, rather than always creating new views. In the case of `CursorAdapter`, the method `hasStableIds()` returns `true` which lets the list know that it is safe to reuse views.

When your list's layout changes, either because the underlying data model has changed or because the position or size of the list view has changed, the view that represents an item will be reused. This is why the color is preserved -- it's the same `View` as before! However,  when `CursorAdapter.bindView()` prepares the view for display it is calling `setText(...)` with the data from the cursor, thus restoring the original text and overwriting your changes. It does not call `setTextColor()`, which is why the text color is preserved. Unless you scroll the view off the screen and back, in which case the view is recycled and all changes are lost.

**TL;DR**

To work around this problem, you could use a custom `SimpleCursorAdapter` that keeps track of the marked item and does something special when re-binding views. You could also use a `ViewBinder`.

```
private MySimpleAdapter mMySimpleAdapter;

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    mMySimpleAdapter.markItemWithId(id);
}

private static class MySimpleAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
    private long mMarkedId = AdapterView.INVALID_ROW_ID;
    ...

    public void markItemWithId(long id) {
        mMarkedId = id;

        // Let the list know that something changed and
        // it needs to update the displayed views.
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super.bindView(view, context, cursor);

        // Give the marked view special treatment.
        if (mMarkedId != AdapterView.INVALID_ROW_ID) {
            final long rowId = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));
            if (rowId == mMarkedId) {
                // Set color, text, etc.
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This could easily be extended to store multiple marked items, additional meta-data, etc.